# Can not deploy my qt app on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, deployment

I created app for building graphics. Just press button, choose file and look to the canvas for visualisation.

I used QGraphicsView for drawing. App works perfectly in debug mode. But when I'm deploying it with AppImage it doesn't work. I press button, choose file and nothing happens. I have no any message or warning.

I didn't use qml. My app is very simple.
List of headers, that I've include:

```
#include <QApplication>
 
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
 
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QThread>
```

look of my release dir:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB9FC.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In Qt Creator check Build Envirnoment variables (paths, libs)

Comment: If it works in debug, I'm sure its problem with dependencies. Have you read this article? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html#creating-the-application-package

Comment: Thanks for all responds. The problem was in std::locale. I used std::stod function and it didn't work properly because locale weren't set. Now everything works perfectly!